# Can I say "you lost me" as "I am lost by you"?

Tags: expressions, past-tense, conjunctions

I learnt that "*You lost me*" means you are talking about something I do not understand.

So if I want to rephrase this sentence as past tense, can I say "*I am lost by you*"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - "You lost me" is a colloquial phrase and your suggestion, while understandable, sounds bizarre.

Note that "you lost me" is informal and might, but doesn't necessarily, suggest that the person trying to explain something to you isn't doing a good job.  Use with some caution!

Comment: As far as tense - "you lost me" already is past tense.  The expression mainly exists in the past tense to indicate that you have already stopped understanding.  "You're losing me" would be the present tense version, but is infrequently used.